# Flex box property to allow uniform display

Tags: html, css

It is hard to describe what I wanted in the titles, I hope this demonstrates it. so if I have `4 divs` with fixed `width`s in a `flex` container and the `flex-wrap` property is set to `wrap` then whenever the container is resized one box will go down until all of them are. but I don't want to have certain situation that happens in between. To demonstrate what I mean I have four pictures here 1,2,3,4 respectively and they demonstrate how the div's look like in different screens.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

So my question is if there is any simple way to make the div's transform from image 1 to image 3 without going though image 2 (to keep the symmetric table view). I can think of a method in js but is there a nice way to do it with just simple css.

Comment: Change the flex-direction to column, and you might need to set width of the children to 100%

Comment: I dont think you understood my question, I am happy with the flex property I just dont like to see the uneven structure like on the second image on resize so rather than going this unsemetric positions I was wondering if there is a way to make your ui jump from 1 to 3

Comment: Ah, sorry apparently I haven't had enough tea this morning.. you could set the width of the children to 50% at that breakpoint so the 3rd child will not have enough room to be on the same line as child 1 and 2. Beyond that, it's working as flex-wrap is supposed to

Comment: Have a coffee on me then:). Changing the width at the break point sounds a great idea I will consider it thank you, let see if other people have other suggestions too.

Comment: you would need to add media queries for your different scenarios

Comment: @Pete i know that but i was hoping if there is way to avoid that using flex-box's

Comment: not with each of your scenarios being so different - you have normal flex for 1 and 4, what looks like align center for 3 on a row and space between for 2 per row, flex isn't magical enough to just change itself based on your wishes, you need to put some work in a prgram it to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something that you want?

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container div:nth-child(even) {
  background: hsla(318, 89%, 61%, 0.89);
}

.container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: hsla(318, 89%, 71%, 0.89);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Resize the window to see the effects.

**Update:**

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.inner-container div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

.inner-container div:nth-child(even) {
  background: hsla(318, 89%, 61%, 0.89);
}

.inner-container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: hsla(318, 89%, 71%, 0.89);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this is what I already have, what I want is not to see the third image. I want to translate from image 1 to image 3. I understand I cand do that with media query's or js but i was wondering if there is a simple css way using flex properties. Thank you!!

Comment: @HileamlakYitayew have you checked CSS grid?

Comment: @HileamlakYitayew I updated my answer. This ain't very much perfect, but you got the idea right?

Comment: You can also achieve the same thing with media queries and grid. Hope this helps!